# How to secure an apache webserver without the mpm_itk module?

Tags: security, apache-2.4

I want to setup a new webserver for public shared hosting under Rocky Linux 9 with apache.

Our old webservers (CentOS 7) have the mpm-itk module installed which assigns a userId and groupId to every request coming in. So if I chown the webfolders of the customers no cross access is possible.

So far so good, but the mpm-itk module is fairly old and therefore not part of the standard repos of RHEL/CentOS/Rocky/etc. anymore, it has performance disadvantages (it uses the old prefork module) and it is not possible to use http/2 or higher with it. And besides all that it poses a security risk.

So my question is, are there alternative modules to use or are there completly different approaches? I've read this article from the [apache wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/PrivilegeSeparation) and I was wondering if there is another solution instead of a reverse proxy?

The ASF has an experimental version of the itk-module by their own ([mod_privileges](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_privileges.html)) But it has the status "experimental" so do not think that this is an official module to use in production. Some other alternatives I found are even older.